# How to filter pandas DataFrame with a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to filter a pandas DataFrame `df` by keeping only the rows which contain one of several strings I have in a `mylist = ['cat', 'mouse']`, in a specific column `df['Title']`:

```
  df.head()

                     Title               Duration   ...       
    0             The Cat1 & Mouse2       33 min    ...          
    1             Legend of the cat       10 min    ...        
    2             Foo-Bar                 3 min     ...      
    3             Legend of Mousopia      5 min     ...          
    4             Cat + Mouse             7 min     ...
```

Looking at similar questions, I have attempted to filter `df` by doing the following:

```
z = df['Title'].str.lower()

df = df[z.contains([x for x in mylist])]
```

Expecting `df.head()` to look something like:

```
                     Title               Duration   ...       
    0             The Cat1 & Mouse2       33 min    ...          
    1             Legend of the cat       10 min    ...                 
    4             Cat + Mouse             7 min     ...
```

However, I keep getting the following **error**:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

I have updated `conda` and `pandas` but keep getting the same result.

```
conda version : 4.5.4
conda-build version : 3.8.0
python version : 3.6.5.final.0
pandas version : 0.23.0           py36h830ac7b_0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df['Title'].str.contains(*my_list)`.