# How to filter a pandas column by list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, list

The standard code for filtering through pandas would be something like:

```
output = df['Column'].str.contains('string')
strings = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
```

Instead of 'string' though, I want to filter such that it goes through a collection of strings in list, "strings". So I tried something such as

```
output = df['Column'].str.contains('*strings')
```

This is the closest solution I could find, but did not work
[How to filter pandas DataFrame with a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853179/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-with-a-list-of-strings)

Edit: I should note that I'm aware of the | or operator. However, I'm wondering how to tackle all cases in the instance list strings is changing and I'm looping through varying lists of changing lengths as the end goal.

Comment: do you want it to contain any or all of the strings in `strings`?

Comment: Any please, but would be nice to know for "all" anyways if you don't mind providing both

Comment: Try `regstr = '|'.join(strings)` and `df['Column'].str.contains(regstr)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a regex string and search using this string.

Like this:
`df['Column'].str.contains('|'.join(strings),regex=True)`

Comment: This seemed to work. Thanks! I also just found df['Column'].isin(strings). The results seems to be identical, but is there any fundamental difference with the code you provided?

Comment: The isin will look for exact matches inside the list. The contains will search for a text in which constains the string you passed in the list, using regex to find it.
For example: `pd.Series(['string 1 foo']).isin(strings)` would return `False`. pd.Series(['string 1 foo']).str.contains('|'.join(strings),regex=True) would return `True`

Answer (score 6):

you probably should look into using `isin()` function ([pandas.Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin)) .

check the code below:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':['string 1', 'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4', 'string 5']})
    strings = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
    output = df.Column.isin(strings)

    df[output]
```

output:

```
        Column
    0   string 1
    1   string 1
    2   string 2
    3   string 2
    4   string 3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Column'

Comment: 'Column' is the name of a column in the dataframe. do a print(df) to see its structure and data. `@bobo32`